# cut copy paste looped instruction betwene two sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have had some answers to my question below, but despite numerous attempts I think my code is now just a total mess, and cannot fathom where it is wrong.

So I have a range A12:N112 that needs sorted on row A with descending values.

Next I need to copy each row (B:L) where column A has a "1" in it and paste it into the first blank row in another workbook, based on column D being blank. I then need to copy the number generated in column A for the row I have just pasted into, and then paste this back into the original row I copied in row N of the first spreadsheet.

I need this then to loop until we reach the first value of "0" in the first spreadsheet.

Here is my code, and although I can get the sort to work, I cannot get anything at all to copy or paste.  This is similar to code i've used before for a single cut copy paste, but cannot get it to work at all here.

```
Dim r As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wkb.Worksheets("Data Entry")
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("\\srveurfcl03.nov.com\IS-GBR-GLBISETNRegister$\Serial No Trial\Serialisation Log.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wkb2.Worksheets("SNo Log")

wkb.Activate
ws.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry").sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry").sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A12:A112"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry").sort
   .SetRange Range("A11:N112")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

For r = 12 To lr
If wkb.ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = 1 Then
    ws.Cells(r, "B:L").Copy

    wkb2.Activate
    ws2.Activate
    Range("D" & Rows.Count).EndX(x1Up).Offset(1).Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wkb.Activate
    ws.Cells(r, 13).Value.Paste
End If
If wkb.ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = 0 Then
   ws.Cells(4, 9).Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Serial No. Issue complete for this OA"
End If
Range("F5").Select
Next r
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it always is.  I've tried to set variables, but cannot get them to work on bits of my code due to object errors so had to go back to the code I know works.  But this only does for fixed ranges, which I will not have in this workbook.

Comment: I do not see a value for your variable lr.

Comment: Don't think this work `ws.Cells(r, "B:L").Copy`, replace with -> `ws.Range(Cells(r, 2), Cells(r, 12)).Copy`

Comment: It looks like there are a number of odd things going on here.  I'd suggest you create a new macro and add things in bit by bit - that way you'll understand yourself when the errors appear.  

As a general note, you may want to add `option explicit` to the top of your code - this will force you to declare each variable properly.  

I'd suggest initially you just try to sort your data - note if you've defined `wkb` and `ws` you can just use the command `wbk.ws.sort.SortFields.Clear`.

If this works successfully, try to get your `for` loop to work for a single row (i.e `r = 12 to 12`)

Comment: Fix your line...`Range("D" & Rows.Count).EndX(x1Up)`, the `EndX` is wrong. If you are going to assign variables, you don't need `Activate`, or `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")`

Comment: Please clarify, your Code...`If wkb.ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = 0 Then
   ws.Cells(4, 9).Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Serial No. Issue complete for this OA"
End If` is just writing the same string into `Range("I4")` for each cell in Col A that = 0

Comment: Also, you can actually accomplish this with out sorting your data.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comments, you don't need to sort your data, or use `Activate`. Using `Range("D" & Rows.Count).EndX(x1Up).Offset(1)` was going in the right direction except you needed to remove the X in `EndX`. Also, the portion of code below does not make any sense. So you need to clarify what you want, to include an example of the outcome, if needed.

```
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wkb.Activate
    ws.Cells(r, 13).Value.Paste
End If
If wkb.ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = 0 Then
   ws.Cells(4, 9).Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Serial No. Issue complete for this OA"
End If
Range("F5").Select
```

The best way to copy a range is to copy the complete range, not line-by-line. The code below will hide any rows from `Range("A12:A112")` that do not have a "1" in column A. It will then copy the visible cells in the range using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and paste to the first empty cell in `ws2.Column(4)`. It then makes all the rows that were hidden visible again. This code will work if your workbook and worksheet variables are correct.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("\\srveurfcl03.nov.com\IS-GBR-GLBISETNRegister$\Serial No Trial\Serialisation Log.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wkb2.Worksheets("SNo Log")

    For Each cell In ws.Range("A12:A112")
        If cell.Value <> "1" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell

    Set Rng = ws.Range("A12:A112").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Rng.Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    ws.Range("A12:A112").EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

Comment: I need to copy the range of rows which have a 1 in column A, but then paste that range into the first blank row in the second spreadhseet.  Then once copied this second sheet will generate a number for each of those rows to be copied back into the first sheet where the rows contain a 1.

Comment: GMalc,  That worked superbly, i've edited the range to copy the cells I need across to the second sheet, but now need to work out how to copy the new numbers back to the first spread sheet.  Especially when the new range would be dynamic, as I said I can do this when I used the old code and for only one cell, but not sure how to do this for this new dynamic range.

Comment: could I set code to count the number of rows which have a 1 in them, then set this as a variable, and after the paste into spreadsheet 2, I use the variable to count UP the same number of cells from the first blank row in the second sheet and copy this number of cells then paste them back into the first spreadhseet?

Comment: First, because i was testing the code, I noticed that i forgot to change the last line to the correct range, `A30` should be `A112`. Yes, you can set a variable to count the number of visible cells from `Range("A12:A112")`.  But I don't really understand why you want to copy the range back to `ws`. Basic code to copy visible cells from the above range is: `Dim rowz As Long` `rowz = Rng.Count`. put these lines below the line that starts with `Set Rng`. to test place `MsgBox rowz` below the new lines. But, you need to clarify why you want to copy from `ws2` back to `ws` in a new question.

Comment: GMalc I am obviously not explaining properly.  so Once the first bot of code has copied all the relevant cells into ws2, and subsequently the formulae in ws.2 column A has generated a serial number, I need to copy those new serial numbers back into the relevant cells in ws column N.  So I have a formulae in ws which will count the number of rows with a 1, and this sets the number of rows UP from the last populated rows in ws2 to copy and then pate into the relevant cells in column N of ws.